# Full join two dataframes by several key columns allowing NA in some of them if just one match occurs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to perform a full join between two dataframes by four key columns `key1,key2,key3,key4`. The condition to match rows is that each match should be unique. So, if one or more key values are NA, but a row can still be matched uniquely to another row from the other df, then the match should be performed. As an example:

```
df1

key1  key2  key3  key4 other1 other2
A      1     ab    10    x    1
B      2     bc    20    x    0
B      2     cd    20    y    0
D      4     de    40    x    1
E      5     ef    50    x    1
.
.
.
.

df2

key1  key2  key3  key4  other3  
A      1     ab    10    100      
B      2     NA    20     10       
D      NA    de    40     75
F      6     fg    50     30
.
.
.
.
```

As you can see, if I perform a normal full_join, then the 3rd row of df2 would not be matched to 4th row of df1. However, due to the nature of my particular study, those rows could be matched. On the contrary, if some row cannot be uniquely matched, then it should not be matched, but appended as a new row. So, my expected output would be the following:

```
key1  key2  key3  key4 other1 other2 other3
A      1     ab    10    x    1       100
B      2     bc    20    x    0       NA
B      2     cd    20    y    0       NA
B      2     NA    20    NA   NA      10
D      4     de    40    x    1       75
E      5     ef    50    x    1       NA
F      6     fg    50    NA   NA      30
```

I tried the following but didn't work, because it does not match rows such as  `D  4 de 40 x 1 75`:

```
merged.df<-df1 %>% full_join(df2, by=c(key1,key2,key3,key4))
```

Do you know how can I solve this?
Thanks!

Comment: So... what are the required conditions for the join? A match in any 3 out of 4 keys?

Comment: @SamR I've edited the question. The condition is that the rows must be uniquely matched. So, if one row has NA in one or more keys but still matches uniquely a specific row from the other dataframe, it should be matched. However, if, for example, one key value is NA and, consequently, there are more than 1 possible matching rows, then this shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Perhaps can you add to your example a case where an NA would not lead to a join?

Comment: But from what I am reading, it sounds like you kind of want to try to fill out missing keys in both tables, using the other table to fill out missing keys if uniquely possible. And afterwards, do the merge - is that what you are trying to do? And if so: are you sure this cannot go wrong, predicting the `NA` key from the other table?

Comment: @Therkel the rows having a `B` in `key` are not joined, they are appended in different rows because they cannot be uniquely matched. No, I am interested to perform a full join; so to merge two df with many different variables into just one df, keeping all their rows and variables. However, I am interested to match as many rows as possible. So, even though some of the keys is unknown, if the rows can still be uniquely matched, I want to get them as the same row, not as different rows

Comment: @Jenifer thanks that makes it clearer. Are the `NA` values guaranteed to be in `df2` or do you also want to match missing values in `df1`?

Comment: @SamR missing values can also exist in df1 and I also would like to match those rows when possible

Comment: So if we had two rows in `df1`, `data.frame(key1 = c("A", "A"), key2 = c(NA, NA), key3 = c("ab", "ab"), key4 = c(10, 10))` we should not be able to fill this out, right? Since `key2` could be two different values?

Comment: Yes! But my aim is not to fill out those NA. That is a consequence of matching the rows between datafarmes. My aim is to merge both dataframes matching as many rows as possible.

Comment: But if you join data with a key missing on another table where the key is not missing, the key will be "found" and filled out. Unless you prefer that the joined row has `NA` in the key where a possible match was found.

Comment: Yes, that is okay. I was just trying to clarify the objective

Comment: @Jenifer no time for an answer but my approach would be: 1. Iterate over all 14 combinations of key matches (run `lapply(1:3, \(x) combn(paste0("key", 1:4), x))` to see them). 2. For each combination, do a left join on the rows with `NA` in excluded columns, (e.g. `left_join(filter(df2, is.na(key3)), df1, by = c("key1", "key2", "key4"), multiple = "all")`. 3. Remove the cases with more than one row. 4. Bind the remaining data frames. 5. Take the unique rows as your new keys. 6. Do a standard join. You still have to decide whether you fill missing values in `df1` or `df2` first - that matters.